# No audio on Nokia Lumia 630

Tags: lumia, audio, nokia-lumia-630, sound

I have no sounds during calls, neither incoming or outgoing, no sounds for music or anything at any time on my Nokia Lumia 630 (Windows Phone 8.1). How can I fix that?

Comment: I assume you've tried pressing the volume up button repeatedly?

Comment: Is this through the speaker, headphone jack, via a Bluetooth headset, or all three?

Answer (score 1):

First, try a soft reset.

If that doesn't help, you should contact Nokia Care.

Answer (score 0):

You can download sysapp pusher and check for update audio setting
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/sysapp-pusher/19d44d9e-f18e-4df1-9bce-36335242ed2e

If it not fix your problem, you can try to restart or reset your phone.